# Información duplicada en for javascript

Tags: javascript, html

tengo un problema con este carrito de compras hecho en javascript que encontré por ahí :D

Tengo una lista de productos y cada producto debe tener un opción de personalizar el producto.

Adjunto imágenes:

Aquí por ejemplo elijo los colores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aquí elijo los tamaños:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al momento de ver mi carrito se añade efectivamente las personalizaciones que elegí pero se repite en el segundo producto.

Para el producto 1 elegí los colores pero para el producto 2 sólo deben aparecerme los tamaños que elegí, en cambio se anteponen los colores seleccionados y luego me aparece el tamaño.

En el producto "Other Box testing" debe aparecerme sólo los tamaños "Pequeño y grande" pero me aparecen "Azul, verde, pequeño, grande."

Adjunto carrito:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dejo el código por aquí:
(cartArray[i].namevar es donde ocurre lo de las personalizaciones "color, tamaño")

```
var shoppingCart = (function() {
    cart = [];
    
    function Item(name, namevar, price, count) {
        this.name = name;
        this.namevar = namevar;
        this.price = price;
        this.count = count;
    }
    var obj = {};

    obj.addItemToCart = function(name, namevar, price, count) {
        for(var item in cart) {
            if(cart[item].name === name) {
                cart[item].count ++;
                saveCart();
                return;
            }
        }
        var item = new Item(name, namevar, price, count);
        cart.push(item);
        saveCart();
    }
    return obj;
})();

$('.add-to-cart').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var name = $(this).data('name');
    var namevar = $(this).data('namevar');
    var price = Number($(this).data('price'));
    shoppingCart.addItemToCart(name, namevar, price, 1);
    displayCart();
});

function displayCart() { 
    var cartArray = shoppingCart.listCart(); 
    var pedidoArray = shoppingCart.listCart(); 
    var showPedidoList = shoppingCart.listCart(); 
    var output = ""; 
    var pedido = ""; 
    var resumen = "";

    for(var i in cartArray) {
        output += "<div class='col-md-12' style='padding:0!important;'>"
                    + "<span class='menu_item title'>"
                        + "<div>"
                            + "<p style='text-align: center;margin:0'>Cantidad:</p>"
                            + "<span class='cantidadAdd'>"
                                + "<button class='minus-item input-group-addon btn_1 outline' data-name='" + cartArray[i].name + "' style='border: 0;font-size:18px;font-weight:600'>-</button>"
                                + "<input type='number' class='item-count' data-name='" + cartArray[i].name + "' value='" + cartArray[i].count + "'>"
                                + "<button class='plus-item btn_1 outline' input-group-addon' data-name='" + cartArray[i].name + "' style='border: 0;font-size:18px;font-weight:600'>+</button>"
                            + "</span>"
                        + "</div>"
                        + "<h3 style='width: 75%;'><b>x"+ cartArray[i].count +"</b> "+ cartArray[i].name +"</h3>"
                        + "<p style='margin:7px 0;width: 75%;'>"+ cartArray[i].namevar +"</p>"
                        + "<strong style='color: gray'>₲ "+ cartArray[i].price.toLocaleString('es-PY') +" c/u</strong><br>"
                    + "</span>"
                + "</div>";
        }
            $('.show-pedido').html(pedido);
            $('.show-cart').html(output);
            $('.showPedidoList').html(resumen);
            $('.totalSend > input').val(shoppingCart.totalCart());
            $('.total-cart').html(shoppingCart.totalCart());
            $('.total-count').html(shoppingCart.totalCount());
    }
    $('.show-cart').on("change", ".item-count", function(event) {
        var name = $(this).data('name');
        var count = Number($(this).val());
        shoppingCart.setCountForItem(name, count);
        displayCart();
    });
displayCart();
```

¿Alguien sabe cómo debo resolverlo?

Comment: 1. te vendría muy bien utilizar *templates strings* 2. acaso no sucede eso por que ambos están seleccionados?

Comment: Sí, pero cada producto tiene sus propias personalizaciones (Ej: Un producto tiene el color y el otro producto tiene el tamaño) y en el carrito me gustaría que aparezca cada producto con su personalización seleccionada. Ambos están seleccionados pero las personalizaciones deben aparecer por separado, en cambio en el segundo producto se repite la personalización del primer producto.

Comment: entonces tienes mal tu estructura, todas las características de un producto deben de estar en la misma parte y no separado

Comment: @Javier ¿podrías agregar la definición de `Item`? Se me ocurre que el problema esta ahí. Aunque también el error puede estar en el `HTML` que generas para mostrar los productos (_antes de agregarlos al carro_)

Comment: @Marcos Item es el constructor
`function Item(name, namevar, price, count) {
  this.name = name;
  this.namevar = namevar;
  this.price = price;
  this.count = count;
 }
 `